# How to make dynamic mod-rewrite for subdirs

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have this dir structure on my webpage:

```
rootOfweb/services/oneservice/service1.php
rootOfweb/services/oneservice/service2.php

rootOfweb/services/anothersercice/service1.php
rootOfweb/services/anothersercice/service2.php

www.example.com/index.php?sideID=nameOfService&p=services/oneservice/service2
```

I have this code in php including files thats needed:

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_GET["p"]))
     {
      $side = $_GET["p"];
      include ($side.'.php');
     }
 ?>
```

I have diffrent names on the diffrent subdirs and i have made one mod_rewrite that work on one of the conditions:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)/([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&p=services/oneservice/$2
```

The aboue rule work for the first service (rootOfweb/services/oneservice/ -all service files -)

I need to create a rule that can work on all subdirs.

Comment: Again the problem is in your pretty URL `http://example.com/services/subfile1` doesn't contain `subdir/YYYY` hence you had to hardcode it in target. If you can keep pretty URL as: `http://example.com/services/subdir/YYYY/subfile1` then one rewrite rule can handle all such situations.

Comment: How would that rewrite look like? Can you come up with a example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from from discussion in comments section above you can have rewrite rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([\w!-]+)/([\w!-]+/[^/]+/[\w!-]+)/?$ index.php?sideID=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will support URLs like these:

```
http://example.com/services/subdir/2014/subfile1
http://example.com/services/subdir/2013/subfile2
http://example.com/services/subdir123/2010/subfile234
```

Comment: What URL did you enter in browser and what is your `$_GET['p']` in the code? I get it as `$_GET[['p'] => subdir/2014/subfile1`

Comment: orginal url: http://example.com/index.php?sideID=services&p=service/painting/learntopaint => http://example.com/painting/learntopaint. This work with the rule i added in question, but by doing this i need a own rule for every subdir inside services.

Comment: Right I know about it but do read my comments below your qestion

Comment: I tryed that, seam it cant fetch the $_GET['p'], somhow it cant read files structure.

Comment: Just forget file structure, just have your links as examples above e.g. `http://example.com/services/subdir/2014/subfile1` with my suggested rule.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63632/discussion-between-sdfgg45-and-anubhava).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just change your regex:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)/([/a-åA-Å0-9_!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&p=subdir/$2
```

Comment: i got subdir/anotherdir/thefile.php, but how to actually replace this with some kinde of regex?