# How to fix redirect when having two RewriteRules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this two rules in my htacces file:

```
   #rewrite pagnition
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_!-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&currentpage=$2
```

output url: http://example.com/blog/2

```
   #rewrite services
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_!-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&p=services/oneservice/$2
```

Output url: http://example.com/services/oneservice

the first one work like a charm, but when accessing the 2th i get problems with the page reloading several times, until the server crashes.

If i disable the first one, the secound work like as it should, if anyone have good soulution for this it wuld be appricciated.

Comment: Have you tried adding the L flag?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/17144329/4154134

Comment: i did, still same issiue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because your both regex are matching same URLs. Tweak your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# output url: http://example.com/blog/2
RewriteRule ^([\w!-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?sideID=$1&currentpage=$2 [L,QSA]

# rewrite services
RewriteRule ^([\w!-]+)/([\w!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&p=services/oneservice/$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Seam to work, but if i want to add another rule: RewriteRule ^([\w!-]+)/([\w!-]+)$ index.php?sideID=$1&p=services/twoservice/$2 [L,QSA]? must regex be diffrent?

Comment: Yes definitely capturing regex should be different in each `RewriteRule`

Comment: can the end part:services/oneservice/$2 be captured to be regexed so i can run one rule? or must it be one rule for eatch like: &p=services/oneservice/$2,&p=services/two/$2 and &p=services/tird/$2

Comment: It can be captured from regex also. What is the original URL and what should be the value of `$1`?

Comment: http://example.com/index.php?sideID=service&p=services/oneservice/service   this loads the service file, witch include another file oneservice.php that can be found in services/onservice, there can be more than one services, so i need to match all subdirs.

Comment: That is you internal URI and what is equivalent pretty URL for `http://example.com/index.php?sideID=service&p=services/oneservice/service`?

Comment: So you want `http://example.com/service/service` => `http://example.com/index.php?sideID=service&p=services/oneservice/service` rewrite. Note that there is no `oneservice` in original URI.

Comment: The other way around: http://example.com/index.php?sideID=service&p=services/oneservice/service => http://example.com/service/service

Comment: Right I understand that but as you note `oneservice` or `twoservice` are not part of pretty URLs hence they cannot be captured from original URL.

Comment: the rewrite rule u pasted aboue works fine, problem is when im gona add more services, i need more rules, exept thise files will have another dir structure on webserver.this part: services/oneservice/filename will be diffrent, i would think somthing like: services/^(.*)$/$2 [L,QSA]. Here ^(.*)$  represent diffrent dirs.

Comment: Actually at this point I would suggest creating a new question with these extended requirements with all these examples in your question so that I and other SO users can understand and help you better. You can link this question in your new question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26531221/how-to-make-dynamic-mod-rewrite-for-subdirs